# How to pass value from DataGridView to RadioButton

Tags: vb.net

How can I pass a value from a DataGridVeiw to a RadioButton in VB.Net?
I have tried the following code but it is not working.

```
If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString.Equals("A") Then
    RadioButton1.Checked = True
ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString.Equals("B") Then
    RadioButton2.Checked = True
End If
```

Comment: Define "Not working"

Comment: What event is this code in?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your database is with "A" spaces, for example it can be like "A ":

```
If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString.Equals("A ")
Then RadioButton1.Checked = True
ElseIf DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value.ToString.Equals("B ")
Then RadioButton2.Checked = True End If
```